# disabling font size trickery in amsart.cls

Tags: fonts, amsart

I know that the ams classes do a lot of font size stuff behind the scenes. Here's my problem: I use some custom fonts for my summation sign, and all that is normally necessary (in the plain old LaTeX `report` or `article` class) is the following line in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\newsum}{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\Sigma$}}}}
```

(yes, I know that TeX normally has different ones for text and math display)

When I typeset a document using `amsart.cls`, I notice that the summation (and product)
signs are smaller than they should be, and that the largest size defined is Huge. What do I need to do to get the summation signs in an `amsart.cls` to be the same as a regular LaTeX document? (pruning `amsart.cls` of the font size code is an acceptable answer, but I would rather not have to do something so extreme if there were just one or two lines I could modify)

Comment: Trying to diagnose the issue - what's wrong with the version that uses \Huge with amsart? That looks to me to be pretty close to the version that uses \huge with the regular article class. Also, I don't know whether it makes a difference, but do you use 10pt, 11pt, or 12pt? It should be possible to find a font size for the sigma that works for you, perhaps by directly using \fontsize{##}{##}\setfont to tweak the size of the font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that `amsart` and `article` have different definitions of the size commands `\large`, `\Large` and so on (which I didn't know until now). Let me assume that you use a base fontsize of `10pt`. Then in `article` you essentially have that `\huge` means

```
\fontsize{\@xxpt}{25}\selectfont
```

where `\@xxpt` is (not `20` but) `20.74`. Thus, you get a fontsize of `20.74pt` and a baselineskip of `25pt`.

In `amsart` you have

```
\fontsize{\@xviipt}{20}\selectfont
```

instead, where `\@xviipt` is `17.28`, so indeed your summation symbol will be a bit smaller. Now you're in luck since `\Huge` in `amsart` is

```
\fontsize{\@xxpt}{24}\selectfont
```

(same fontsize, as Carl already saw, but slightly smaller baselineskip), so using `\Huge` instead of `\huge` will indeed be your solution in this case. In other cases, you should make a manual choice with `\fontsize{##}{##}\selectfont`, as Carl suggests in his comment.